# Creating criteria with many-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have many-to-many bidirectional mapping with my classes A and B. In POJO A has set of B instances, B has set of A instances. How to query A classes that have specific two (or more) instances of B ? for example b1, b2, b3. ALL OF THESE.

```
criteria.createalias("bs", "b");
for(B b : collectionOfB){
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("b.id", b.getId()));
}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: No, its generating wrong SQL, creates left outer join with b table and add condition "where b.id = 1 and b.id=2", which return 0 rows (even if a record have connections with b1 and b2).

Comment: Something like below


`for (LicenceClass licenceClass : licenceClasses) {               
    criteria.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("? = some(select " + LicenceClass.PRIMARY_KEY + " from " +
                    LICENCE_CLASS_JOIN_TABLE + "  where {alias}." +
                    DriversLicence.PRIMARY_KEY + " = " + DriversLicence.PRIMARY_KEY + ")",
                    licenceClass.getId(), Hibernate.LONG));
}`


LICENCE_CLASS_JOIN_TABLE is the name of the table that hibernate generates to support the many-to-many relationship between driversLicence and LicenceClass.